# Convert uploaded songs to shareable version in YouTube Music

Tags: upload, file-conversion, youtube-music

Due to Google Play Music being sunset, I had to move all of my uploaded music from Google Play Music to YouTube Music. One nice feature about YouTube Music is the ability to share playlists with others. However, I realized that shared playlists do not show uploaded music in them when shared with others. They only show to the creator of the playlist.

Is there a way to automatically convert uploaded songs to a public version of the song that is visible to others? All of my music is properly titled with the correct artists. I'm surprised that I haven't seen any sort of functionality like this built into YouTube Music. A third party solution is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: Try [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/)!

As you are not very specific about the playlist, and YouTube tightly controls this kind of content to avoid harming artists, then they probably disable this feature on your channel.

Comment: Does SoundCloud allow you to upload your entire music library? I believe not.

Comment: Also YouTube Music is a completely separate application than YouTube is. YouTube Music allows you to upload audio files (not videos) which is what I'm talking about when I say "uploaded songs".